# Cannot scroll element into view in Firefox using Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I try to click element that doesn't appear in page then I use "keyword Scroll Element Into View" but it doesn't scroll into view and Robot return element is not clickable at point.

```
I try these way: Nothing happen and cannot click 
Scroll Element Into View         &{quickLink}[sendDoc]
Set Focus To Element    ${PRODUCT}
Click Element      ${PRODUCT}                              

And these way: it scroll to the bottom of page and cannot click
Wait Until Element Is Visible    ${PRODUCT}   timeout=30s
${x}=        Get Horizontal Position  ${PRODUCT}
${y}=        Get Vertical Position    ${PRODUCT}
Execute Javascript  window.scrollTo(${x}, ${y})
Set Focus To Element    ${PRODUCT}
Click Element      ${PRODUCT}
```

ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element  is not clickable at point (453.75,186.5) because another element  obscures it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of scrolling, you have more options:

1) Resize your browser, so you dont need to scroll (use xvfb to create a screen with a specific size, then use Set Window Size)

2) I guess only using "Wait Until Element Is Visible" is enough. No need to scroll

Comment: I already used keyword "Set Window Size    1382  1400" then it's able to click ${PRODUCT}  but it cannot find element in next step even though in Capture Page Screenshot displays that element

Comment: It works now by use keyword "Set Window" thank you for your idea.